# How can I add strikethrough text animation using jQuery dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My requirement is to add strikethrough i.e. to add strike on the text dynamically, from left to right animation using CSS and jQuery. I tried adding animation, but when the text changes the strike remains I want to reset the strike on the next interval and then add strike vice-versa.

Following is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aj6h4pLc/

Example GIF of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

```js
var texts = ["This", "is a", "example"];
var count = 0;

function changeText() {
  $("span.strikethrough").text(texts[count]);
  document.getElementById("example").style.transform = "transition: transform 1000s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1);"
  count < 3 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(changeText, 500);
```

```css
.strikethrough {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.strikethrough:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -0.7em;
  background: clear;
  transform-origin: center left;
  animation: change 3s 5s infinite, strikethrough 3s 5s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1) 1;
}

@keyframes strikethrough {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    background-color: black
  }
  100% {
    background-color: black
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="example" class="strikethrough">Start</span>
```

Comment: Not clear to me, which exactly results do you want to get. You want to see how words gradually changes each other, with smoothly disable "line-through" css property?

Comment: I want to add strike on the text and when next comes in i want to add strike after some secs. Currently in my code the strike remains everytime.

Comment: I think this is what she wants: [demo](https://i.imgur.com/napBa8K.gif)

Comment: @SirExotic yes, my requirement is like this

Comment: @divyadave I think my updated answer is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first solution is to add a wrapper and a nother `div` with `postion : absolute`. The div with absolute will be your line. It would look somthing like this:

```js
var texts = ["This", "is a", "example"];
var count = 0;
//var active = true;
function changeText() {
    $('.line').addClass('line_disabled')
    $('.line').width('0px')
    $("span.strikethrough").text(texts[count]);
    $('.line').removeClass('line_disabled')
    $('.line').width($("span.strikethrough").width())

    count < 2 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(changeText, 1000);
```

```css
.strikethrough {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.wrapper{
  position:relative;
}

.line{
  position: absolute;
  margin:auto;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:2px;
  background-color:black;
  transition:all 0.6s ease;
}
.line_disabled{
  width:0px !important;
  transition:none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="example" class="strikethrough">Start</span>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to make strike responsive currently the strike is not the words when the screen size is changed. I tried make left as % still it doesn't work, do have any idea how this can be done?